# Density splits and Google Play filters

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play

I'm in a middle of migration process from `Eclipse` to `Android Studio` and just stambled across [the density split option](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits), which in my case would be great (but never dared to try it with `Eclipse`).

I have an app on Google Play with 3 sets of graphics (fat, one `.apk`) - `mdpi`, `hdpi` and `xhpi` and I don't filter devices with other density - they just use scaled graphics.

I've tried gradle `splits` option in a following way:

```
splits {
    density {
        enable true
        exclude "ldpi", "tvdpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi"
        compatibleScreens 'normal', 'large', 'xlarge'
    }
}
```

and it builds 3 version of my `.apk` - `myApp-mdpi`, `myApp-hdpi` and `myApp-xhdpi` as expected.

The question is - if I update my current fat app with these 3 density-specific versions what will happen to devices with other density (which are marked as *excluded* above) - `ldpi`, `tvdpi`, `xxhdpi`, `xxxhdpi` and others? Will they receive ppi-closest version, or will they be filtered and will not see my app at all?

As you can imagine, it's important for me not to filter other devices; I cannot find any documentation on this, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that easily with using so-called "fat" apk file (universal one).

Just remember that this apk needs to have the lowest versionCode of them all.

Take a look at this screen

[image]

Let's say that you've got an HDPI device. There is a version 40100400 available for it (the universal one), but also, it is eligible to download 40100424 version (the 'newer' one).

For XXXHDPI version, the only available version is the 40100400 (same for LDPI, TVDPI etc.)